# Not able to add VideoLAN VLC component in VB6

Tags: vb6, activex, webcam, vlc, name-conflict

I want to create a simple VB project which would play live feed from a CCTV webcam on the form. For this, I am planning to embed VLC in my VB form. I have installed VLC on my PC already. In the components list I get entry for VLC activeX component as well.

However, when I try to add the same to my project, an error occurs. A popup appears as follows:

[image]

I have already tried some solutions as suggested on net. However, I am not able to solve this nagging issue.

My system config is: Win XP 32-bit SP3, Visual Basic 6, VLC 2.0.1

Also, my ultimate requirement is to play webcam feed on the form. And I thought VLC suits the best because it can play webcam feed directly. If there are any other solutions available, I would be thankful to know them also.

Let me know if any additional details are required.

Comment: Did you try re-installing VLC?
Usually a name conflict means that there is another component in your project that also has the same name as another component.  Did you happen to also make a reference to VLC from the Project References?  If so that could cause this error to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this should be a separate answer, but here is the actual answer and solution!

This code references VideoLan VLC ActiveX Plugin - axvlc.dll and requires nothing but a blank form
Note: Add via References, not via the Components > Controls.

```
Dim vlcControl As Object
Dim WithEvents vlcPlayer As AXVLC.VLCPlugin2

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set vlcControl = Controls.Add("VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2", "vlcControl")

    vlcControl.Height = 6000
    vlcControl.Width = 10000
    vlcControl.Visible = True

    Set vlcPlayer = vlcControl.object

    ' I haven't figured out how to get this to play local files...
    vlcPlayer.playlist.Add ("http://url.com/video.mp4")
    vlcPlayer.playlist.play
End Sub


Private Sub vlcPlayer_MediaPlayerPlaying()
    Debug.Print "Playing"
End Sub


Private Sub vlcPlayer_MediaPlayerEndReached()
    Debug.Print "Stopped"
End Sub
```

Edit: This is a separate example that does not require References:

This code requires nothing but a blank form and VLC ActiveX installed/registered
Note: You do not have access to VLC event triggers

```
Dim vlcControl As Object

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set vlcControl = Controls.Add("VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2", "vlcControl")

    vlcControl.Height = 6000
    vlcControl.Width = 10000
    vlcControl.Visible = True


    ' I haven't figured out how to get this to play local files...
    vlcControl.object.playlist.Add ("http://url.com/video.mp4")
    vlcControl.object.playlist.play
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is a problem with the VLC plugin, the web is riddled with this problem dating back before 2012 and it has nothing to do with you, your computer, or your installation.

The problem is simple, and the error is telling you exactly whats going on. Old plugins worked fine with VB6 and when you added the control, it added **2 different controls** to the VB6 toolbox. Not sure what the difference is, but the problem is, the **two controls have the same name**. When VB6 tries to add this control, its trying to add two different controls, that now have the same system name, which VB6 does not allow.

Spread the word, don't let any noobs tell you to reinstall VLC because that wont get you anywhere, you need an old old version of VLC. :)

Comment: Found out a little more, this is caused by the developers choosing to deprecate the original control and functions and creating a second control/functions within the same ActiveX. Some naming conflict occurred way back in v1.1.0 between the deprecated version and the current version of the ActiveX causing the issue. You will need to get a version before v1.1.0 to use with VB6. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me because these old versions don't play m3u8 files without skipping (even locally..).

Answer (score 0):

```
vlc.playlist.Add ("file:///C:\video.mp4")
```